# join a polygon shape to the attributes contained in a shape containing three points

Tags: shapefile

I need to join a polygon shape to the attributes contained in a shape containing three points ( all within the polygon ) with different information.

Using the command  merge attributes by position  I get a new shape that includes only the attributes of the first point .

Is there a command to acquire the attributes of the three points so that querying the polygon I have the attributes of the three points on one line in the table ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE silvia! Could you please add the GIS software and version you are using please? Also, it sounds like you might want to use a tool like **Join attributes by location**.

Comment: You will need to do this in 3 steps, first spatial join the polygon to the points, then use pivot table on the points by polygon ID, and finally join the output to the polygon layer based on the polygon ID